# MB300 phone: magnetic field sensor mounted incorrectly?

Tags: android, android-hardware

according to the android specs all the sensors must have their axes oriented the same way, as specified in:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

I have two Motorola phones: mb300 and motorola flipout.

In the flipout the magnetic field sensor is mounted correctly. But in the mb300 they swapped the X and Y axes.
By testing I confirmed that the *accelerometer* is mounted correctly on both phones and the values agree with
each other. But regarding the magnetic field sensors the values don't agree, but they started too agree after I performed the following operation on the mb300:

(data is the array SensorEvent.values)

```
if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) { //becauseof mb300 phone
    float swap;
    swap = -data[1]; //x = -y
    data[1] = data[0]; //y = x
    data[0] = swap;
}
```

I have tested this carefully.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Answer (score 0):

Mounting of the all the sensor ICs in the same orientation is
often not possible on mobiles phones. Due to the small space
available to stuff in a lot of hardware, we often encounter
the situation which you describe.

Let me say that, there is nothing "wrong" in this.

Once you have swapped the axes properly, (in driver/HAL)
the Android framework will always get the proper data.

There will be no "side-effects" if you have swapped the axes accordingly.

Regards
CVS@2600Hertz

Comment: I would agree about the physical constraints and ability of software to compensate.  However it seems like the MB300 runs android officially, so shouldn't this mapping within the framework have been done by the manufacturer's porting engineers?   It seems wrong for the poster to appear to be having to deal with it in what appears to be application code.

Comment: I agree with Chris above. If I code software for the Android I operate under the assumption that all Android devices will behave consistently. How can I know which of the 1000s of cell phones will need specific fixes? I don't even know if the problem mentioned is just in the specific phone I have or in all phones of that model.

Comment: Exactly! Its the responsibility of the ODM/OEM to identify & fix this.